# Need help with a quiz question please

Tags: theory, learning

Which statement best describes an interval?

- A. the lowest pitch of each chord
- B. chords performed in specific order
- C.  the musical distance between two points
- D. a chord containing three pitches

So I originally answered with C, but I guess that was wrong. Can anyone please explain to me which it is? I was originally thinking it was D, but i'm not sure if I was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is most definitely C, "the musical distance between two points." (And in really academic music theory, it becomes *generalized* even more!)

If you put C and it was marked incorrect, then it was graded incorrectly. Contact your teacher, because your answer is right!

Comment: Ok thank you very much, Honestly I thought it was C but my teacher marked it as wrong which for some reason I don't know why. I will contact my teacher, thank you very much! :D

Comment: Jesus, this is so simple! Does your teacher know music theory?

Comment: To be fair, we all make mistakes when we have to grade 30 of these exams in a row :-)

Comment: Haha very true :) Honestly, no hate to teachers at all so I understand it gets tough :)

Answer (score 2):

To be completely clear, answer C is not precisely correct, but it is the best of the available answers.  To be precisely correct it would have to include the word 'vertical' somewhere.  An interval is the vertical distance between two musical points.  (If the distance was horizontal, the answer should involve the word 'duration.')

Comment: +1. A, B and D are just plain wrong. C is close to being meaningless. (For example what on earth is it supposed to mean if the two "points" are the start and the end of the piece?). So, if you want to get a good grade, pick C, but if you want to learn something about music theory, find a better course!

Comment: __ (If the distance was horizontal, the answer should involve the word 'duration.') __